# Apply the Grid Changes in Chart without using SharedDateSource?

Tags: data-binding, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my project  having same data-source for grid and chart, but need to display all the data on the chart in page load and  Display the grid data in button click.

But previously we used shared data-source so can easily apply the grid changes in the chart.
Now used separate variable for grid and chart and apply the `"AutoBind=true"` for chart and `"AutoBind=false"` both are not working and grid changes has to apply to chart.

how to give relation for both grid and chart?

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bchz/108/):

```js
var sharedDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
            OrderDate: { type: "date" }
            }
        }
    } 
});
var DataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
    },
    schema   : {
        model: {
            fields: {
                OrderDate: { type: "date" }
            }
        }
    }   
});
```

Comment: can any one help me for this solution

Comment: ok thank you skippy ya i can post now

Comment: means your telling to me make upvotes using another account?

Comment: so i have to reversed that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using shared datasource is correct approach. Here is fiddle with fixed code meeting your requirements : http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/kappG/2/.
The autoBind property expects boolean not string (eg.: true not "true").

```
autoBind: true,
```